# IE disable auto invalid checked asp.net/VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer

I have a trouble with IE , please support to me .Thank you very much

---

I use maxlength attribute for my text box control to check valid

Example : length is 10 .

After I get data form Database which has length is bigger than , ex 12 . 
And set this value to my control .

---

only IE browser shows stranger things as image bellows .

How should i turn off them .

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: You mean that IE complains in another language than you expected, or that it complains at all?

Comment: Language is ok , but the red border and the message popup are stranger things which I said . I think they are belong to IE , because  google chrome don't have them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason .

From IE-10 ,11 to newest version, IE provides the valid checking .

if we don't want to use it .We can force IE to version 9 by this code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Best regards.